# Parsing <cap:event>, <cap:urgency> tags value using feedparser in python from a Atom/xml feed

Tags: python-3.x, feedparser, thonny

I am using feedparser for parsing data from an Atom/xml feed file. The link for the file is:

https://alerts.weather.gov/cap/oh.php?x=0

This is a feed that is put out by the National Weather Service for providing weather alert information. This feed uses a Common Alert Protocol (CAP) alert messaging. I'm trying to parse out the following:

```
<summary>...AIR QUALITY ADVISORY IN EFFECT UNTIL MIDNIGHT EDT TONIGHT... The Miami Valley Regional Planning Commission and the Regional Air Pollution Control Agency have issued an Air Pollution and Air Quality Advisory for Montgomery, Miami, Greene, Clark, Preble and Darke counties in the Miami Valley Region, until midnight EDT tonight.</summary>
<cap:event>Air Quality Alert</cap:event>
<cap:effective>2020-06-08T15:15:00-04:00</cap:effective>
<cap:expires>2020-06-09T19:30:00-04:00</cap:expires>
<cap:status>Actual</cap:status>
<cap:msgType>Alert</cap:msgType>
<cap:category>Met</cap:category>
<cap:urgency>Unknown</cap:urgency>
<cap:severity>Unknown</cap:severity>
<cap:certainty>Unknown</cap:certainty>
<cap:areaDesc>Clark; Darke; Greene; Miami; Montgomery; Preble</cap:areaDesc>
```

I can parse out the summary but I can't parse out the  tags like  or  for example using feedparser. This is what I need for a Raspberry Pi project. I've tried many different approaches such as:

```
d = feedparser.parse('http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/ms.php?x=0')
print (d.entries[0].['cap_event'])
print (d.entries[0]['cap:event'])
```

When I try print (d.entries[0].['cap_event']), I get following error:

> > > %Run feedparser2.py
> > >         File "/home/n8mdp/MyPythonApps/feedparser2.py", line 13
> > >           print (d['entries'][0].['cap:event'])
> > >                                  ^
> > >       SyntaxError: invalid syntax

If I use print (d.entries[0]['cap_event'], it get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/n8mdp/MyPythonApps/feedparser2.py", line 13, in 
    print (d['entries'][0]['cap:event'])
  File "/home/n8mdp/.thonny/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/feedparser.py", line 356, in **getitem**
    return dict.**getitem**(self, key)
KeyError: 'cap:event'

> > > 

Using Thonny 2.1.16 in Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. Feedparser is installed.

Does any one have a good suggestion on how I can parse those tags using feedparser in python?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After deeper investigation, I determined that the following worked:

```
print (alertFeed['entries'][nws_entry_id]['id'])
print (alertFeed['entries'][nws_entry_id]['summary'])
print (alertFeed['entries'][nws_entry_id]['cap_event'])
print (alertFeed['entries'][nws_entry_id]['cap_urgency'])
print (alertFeed['entries'][nws_entry_id]['cap_areadesc'])
```

nws_entry_id is the index of the number of entries in the feed. Had to actually review the feed as returned by feedparser to identify this. Now the code is working as expected.